# Navigate to a page on the basis of time

Tags: flutter

How to navigate to a page on flutter app on the basis of time and date.
For ex. i want all the current users of the app to be navigated to a particular page at let's say 3 PM.

Comment: You might want to check out https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager .

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.now()` gives you the current date and time.

```
if(DateTime.now().hour == 15){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => new Page(),
    ));
}
```